# How to get specific property value in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Is there a way using REST but avoiding aql to get specific custom property value in Artifactory.
Artifact name, repo and property key are known.
Get on artifact path does not show custom properties at all.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that what you are looking for is this link titled: [Artifactory REST API - Item Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties)

This is how the REST will look like:

```
$ curl -uadmin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/repository/path/to/file.jar?properties"
```

This REST API will return the artifact properties. Now in order to get a specific property, you need to pass it in the REST as follows:

```
$ curl -iuadmin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/repository/path/to/file.jar?properties=build.name"
```

In the REST above I will get the value of the property that is named "build.name". You can replace it with any key that you need.

Comment: With this query I need to know an exact path to the artifact. And this request does not consist of custom item properties unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand. You say that you have the artifact name, you have the repository that it is placed, you have the property name, but you don't have the full path to the file? If so there is no way of getting the property value. Let's think of a scenario where you have 2 artifacts with the same name inside a repository, placed on two different paths and both has the same property name but different values, which should be returned in your scenario? 

I think you will need to do this in 2 steps, first,  search for the artifact and then use the full path for the property search.

Comment: As a comment what it is not possible right now is to get properties for the latest SNAPSHOT. See this ticket  https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6389

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
curl --silent --show-error "http://your-artifactory-server:8081/artifactory/api/storage/my_repo/some_path1/some_path2/artifact_file.txt?properties
```

it will output:

```
{
 "properties": {
     "prop1": [ "value1" ],
     "prop2": [ "value2" ],
     ...
     ....
  },
  "uri": "http://your-artifactory-server:8081/artifactory/api/storage/my_repo/some_path1/some_path2/artifact_file.txt"
}
```

If you wanted to get the value of a given property, then try this:

```
curl --silent --show-error "http://your-artifactory-server:8081/artifactory/api/storage/my_repo/some_path1/some_path2/artifact_file.txt?properties | grep "prop2" | sed "s/[\"\[ ,]//g;s/]//g" | cut -d':' -f2
```